# MySQL - How can I combine information from different rows in one table into a single row in another?

Tags: mysql, database, rows

I have a table which is a huge list of all the information that was filled into a form. Each form entry put all the information into the same column, with another column for field_id (and this lets me know exactly where the information was entered). So if the form had 8 entry fields, all the info that was entered would be in one column, and the field_id corresponding to the field it was entered into is in another field.

I am now rebuilding the db to make this mess of a system more useful, but I need to keep all the previously entered data. How can I combine the information from the 8 rows where information was entered into a single row in the new table, based on the field_id column?

So if name/address/phone/email/fax/mother/father/pet were the columns of the new table, but the info for each of these was stored in a single column in the original table with field_ids 1 to 8 in another column, how could I go about doing this?

EDIT: Clearer

Table1 structure:
id/meta_value/field_id/entry_id/created_date

Table2 structure:
id/name/address/phone/email/fax/mother/father/pet

Comment: Could you post the structure of the two tables? The `field_id` will identify columns, but your question doesn't mention what identifies *rows*. In other words, there must be a value that ties the 8 rows together.

Comment: The 8 rows are tied together for each entry by entry_id. So each set of 8 rows will have a unique one of these.

How do I post up the structure of each db?

Comment: Both of the answers below will pivot the 8 rows into a single row. You'll have to adapt them for your actual table and column names. If you have trouble making the leap and need an example based on your own tables, just edit your question and add something like "TableA has columns entry_id, field_id, field_value and TableB has columns this, that, other". That'll be enough to go on.

Comment: Yeah I put that in there. I'll try work it myself and check back to see if anyone else comes to the rescue. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good, and good luck! I hate to pick favorites, but I think you'll find the @SGeddes answer easier to adapt.

Comment: I thought so too. If I wanted to insert the rows into another table, would I just start with INSERT INTO table2 SELECT blahblahblah...?

Comment: Exactly, but I'd recommend working it out with the `SELECT` part only. Once that's looking good you can go to the `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `MAX` and `CASE`.  Not knowing your table structure, I'll just give you an example:

```
SELECT id,
   MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 1 THEN meta_value END) 'Name',
   MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 THEN meta_value END) 'Address',
   MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 3 THEN meta_value END) 'Phone',
   ...
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
```

This will `PIVOT` your results into a single row with multiple columns.

Comment: If I wanted to insert this row into another table, would I just start with INSERT INTO table2 SELECT blahblahblah...?

Comment: @Sw1sh -- does your other table exist?  If so, then yes, you can use INSERT INTO...  Give it a shot and let me know if you run into any issues.  Best regards!

Comment: Yeah, it's already there and created. I'm gonna give it a whack now and I'll post back to let you know.

Comment: Sounds good -- maybe this will help as well -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/575e5b/1 -- Good luck!

Comment: It seems to have worked, thanks dude! But I think it's creating duplicates. Is there any reason it might be doing this, or would it be an issue with the original table?

Comment: @Sw1sh - not sure how it could create duplicates since we're grouping by id -- that should ensure the ids are unique.

Comment: Yeah I checked the original table and there were multiple entries of the same info. It's working fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if i understand correctly, you can do something like:

```
select
    id,
    (select meta_value from Table1 t2 where field_id = 1 and t2.id = t1.id) as name,
    (select meta_value from Table1 t2 where field_id = 2 and t2.id = t1.id) as address,
    ...
    (select meta_value from Table1 t2 where field_id = 8 and t2.id = t1.id) as pet
from Table1 t1
group by id
```